# SQL AND Constraint Causing Performance Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, indexing

I have a seemingly simple query case where adding a constraint causes a major performance decrease.  The three columns that are being constrained with the AND clause, are all bigints.  If I use any two of them (but not all three) the query runs instantaneously, but as soon as I add a third AND, it runs slow.

```
WITH tb AS (SELECT
   DISTINCT u.*  
FROM
   [user] u  
INNER JOIN
   user_personal up 
      ON up.user_id = u.user_id        
WHERE
   1=1  
   AND u.site_instance_id = 1      
   AND u.graduation_class_id = 27  
   AND u.graduation_term_id IN (76,75) 
   ) SELECT
   COUNT (*) AS count 
FROM
   ( SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
   ORDER BY
      last_name ASC) AS row,
      * 
   FROM
      tb) sub
```

Does this have to do with the fact that all three of those columns are bigint? Or does it have to do with table indexes on those columns? (I don't have any indexes set up for those columns).  Or could it be something else?

Note - in this case the AND u.site_instance_id = 1 is redundant, but it shouldn't matter, should it?

EDIT After using SET showplan_all ON:

```
 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1008],0)))
   |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=Count(*)))
        |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, WHERE:(.[dbo].[user].[user_id] as [u].[user_id]=.[dbo].[user_personal].[user_id] as [up].[user_id]))
             |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:(.[dbo].[user].[PK__user__B9BE370F7F60ED59] AS [u]), WHERE:(.[dbo].[user].[site_instance_id] as [u].[site_instance_id]=(1) AND .[dbo].[user].[graduation_class_id] as [u].[graduation_class_id]=(27) AND (.[dbo].[user].[graduation_term_id] as [u].[graduation_term_id]=(75) OR .[dbo].[user].[graduation_term_id] as [u].[graduation_term_id]=(76))))
             |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:(.[dbo].[user_personal].[PK__user_per__C701FAD641EDCAC5] AS [up]))
```

... and with only TWO AND clauses...

```
|--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1008],0)))
       |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=Count(*)))
            |--Hash Match(Left Semi Join, HASH:([u].[user_id])=([up].[user_id]), RESIDUAL:(.[dbo].[user].[user_id] as [u].[user_id]=.[dbo].[user_personal].[user_id] as [up].[user_id]))
                 |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:(.[dbo].[user].[PK__user__B9BE370F7F60ED59] AS [u]), WHERE:(.[dbo].[user].[graduation_class_id] as [u].[graduation_class_id]=(27) AND (.[dbo].[user].[graduation_term_id] as [u].[graduation_term_id]=(75) OR .[dbo].[user].[graduation_term_id] as [u].[graduation_term_id]=(76))))
                 |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:(.[dbo].[user_personal].[PK__user_per__C701FAD641EDCAC5] AS [up]))
```

Comment: What does the execution plan say? I'm guessing there will be a Scan in there.

Comment: Try using `set showplan on`

Comment: Pasting some helpful info in original post after setting showplan_all on.

Comment: No, it is all of the nested queries combined with the join.  You should first work on simplifying the query, and then look into caching results.  One major thing that will help is if you do not actually need all of the items returned by u.*

Comment: If you look at the estimated execution plan, does it have any suggestions for indexes?

Also, what does the query plan look like with only two of the AND clauses?

Comment: Just posted the plan with just two clauses

Comment: Looks like the addition of the and makes it believe the query will be more selective so chooses a nested loops rather than a hash join. What are the actual vs estimated number of rows for the inputs to the join?

Comment: Ill make the index on site_instance_id.  The number of returned rows is 365 in ALL cases.  Not sure how to check the estimated.

Comment: @Hogan - What type of index should I make on site_instance_id?

Comment: Run the query with the include actual execution plan option selected in ssms and mouse over the arrows in the graphical plan to see the estimates. Or 'set statistics profile on' run both and post the results.

Comment: @AdamLevitt - Nevermind -- Martin is right, it is the HASH vs NESTED

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input and help! I was missing the index on user_personal.user_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand your question -- @Hogan had a much simpler version of your query.  Nonetheless, you should have Indexes on each of the fields you join on and any field you consistently search upon.

In your case, I'd make sure you have the following indexes:

- user.user_id (presumably already has PK)
- user_personal.user_id
- user.site_instance_id, user.graduation_class_id and user.graduation_term_id

You may also consider adding indexes to each of the 3 fields in your WHERE criteria individually, but this should prove to yield a better performance.  Plus, use @Hogan's query instead.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The issue was the missing index on user_personal.user_id!

Answer (score 1):

There must be more to the story.  Clearly the following is the same as the code posted and simpler (and I expect faster):

```
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id)) as count
  FROM [user] u  
  INNER JOIN  user_personal up ON up.user_id = u.user_id        
  WHERE
   u.site_instance_id = 1   AND   
   u.graduation_class_id = 27  AND
   u.graduation_term_id IN (76,75)
```

Comment: That code is simpler and very slightly faster, but the performance hit remains with the third join, surprisingly.

Comment: The 3rd term being the graduation term?

Comment: it actually doesn't matter which of the three clauses I remove.  As soon as I remove any of the three, the query comes back instantaneously.